# Run Excel Macro and Save File through Windows Task

Tags: vba, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to create a Windows Task that refreshes an Excel macro and saves the new file, while I am not logged onto the server, once a day. I have a Windows Task that runs a VBS script that successfully runs a macro that refreshes data through a data connection, and refreshes the pivot tables based on that data. It only works if I am logged onto the server, whether on a schedule or run manually. But if I'm not logged on, the script doesn't run successfully, and the macro is not refreshed nor file saved. I have changed the Windows Task Scheduler settings to run whether or not I am logged on, and with the highest privileges.

Here is the macro:

```
Public Sub Refresh()
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("pr prp").Refresh
Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = Sheets("Days to Available").PivotTables("PivotTable9")
    pt.RefreshTable
Sheet1.Worksheet_PivotUpdate

Dim pt1 As PivotTable
    Set pt1 = Sheets("Days to Available (by site)").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    pt1.RefreshTable
Sheet2.Worksheet_PivotUpdate

Dim pt3 As PivotTable
    Set pt3 = Sheets("Available").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    pt3.RefreshTable
Sheet6.Worksheet_PivotUpdate

Dim pt4 As PivotTable
    Set pt4 = Sheets("Days to Available (preg)").PivotTables("PivotTable4")
    pt4.RefreshTable
Sheet7.Worksheet_PivotUpdate

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Here is the vbs script:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\mr\Availability\Availability Archives\Availability_w.xlsm'!Module1.Refresh"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

How do I automate this process while I'm not logged on?

Comment: Did you set the task to run using your Windows login credentials ?

Comment: Yes, I used my Windows login credentials.

Comment: Any errors logged when it fails?

Comment: No, it actually says it runs successfully, but it usually takes about 2 minutes to update, and it goes from starting to "finishing successfully" in the same second, but without saving the file based on the timestamp of the file save date, and based on the data not being updated.

Comment: Maybe an issue in your macro - if it runs differently when you're not logged in?  What does the data connection connect to?

Comment: I just changed the dcom config on Excel to run with the user I'm logged in as for the for windows task and it works when I'm not logged on now. It's not ideal since I can't open the Excel files outside of the server, or within it - but it works.

Comment: Kind of an old link but may be useful - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run/